# Remove elements from several lists at the same index position

Tags: python, list

My program has many lists that are dependent on each other. What I need is when I remove an element from the main list (called LIST_5) by index, it will remove the corresponding index on all other lists.

I'm stuck after deleting only the elements from the main list (LIST_5), and I have no idea how to do the same for the other lists.

```
LIST_1 =  ['english', 'english', 'french', 'english', 'english', 'english']
LIST_2  = ['documentation', 'music', 'position', 'social media', 'microeconomics', 'financial equations']
LIST_3 = ['ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12']
LIST_4 = ['141031', '141032', '141033', '141034', '141035', '141036']
LIST_5 = ['allowed', 'allowed', 'rejected', 'allowed', 'rejected', 'allowed']

for L5 in LIST_5:
    if 'allowed' in L5: 
        pass
    else:
        LIST_5.remove(L5)
print(LIST_5)
# OUTPUT:
# ['allowed', 'allowed', 'allowed', 'allowed']
# How to apply the removal process for all other lists?
```

**So the output of that would be:**

```
# LIST_1 =  ['english', 'english', 'english', 'english']
# LIST_2  = ['documentation', 'music', 'social media', 'financial equations']
# LIST_3 = ['ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12']
# LIST_4 = ['141031', '141032', '141034', '141036']
# LIST_5 = ['allowed', 'allowed', 'allowed', 'allowed']
```

Comment: i'd go with
for arr in (LIST_1, LIST_2, LIST_3, etc): for L in arr: if 'allowed' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, it's not beautifull but it works:

```
for i in range(len(LIST_5)-1, -1, -1):
    if 'allowed' in LIST_5[i]: 
        pass
    else:
        LIST_1.pop(i)
        LIST_2.pop(i)
        LIST_3.pop(i)
        LIST_4.pop(i)
        LIST_5.pop(i)
```

Pop deletes element on index, we go in reverse so we don't mess up our indexes.

Edit: The range() function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 by default, and increments by 1 (by default), and stops before a specified number.

So if we look at range function as **range(start, stop, step)**, my range specifies to go from len(LIST_5)-1 (in this case 5) to 0 (we set stop as -1 because it will stop one step before it) by step -1, so it goes in reverse.
You can read more here: https://realpython.com/python-range/

As to why we are doing it in reverse? If we did it from 0 upwards and deleted elements at index 2 our lists would be shorter, so our iteration would go out of bounds at some point. By doing it in reverse we avoid this issue, as indexes that we need to check don't change.

Comment: It does work for me but can you clarify the range parameters you used in the loop.

Comment: @BACHASH Added some clarification and corrected my mistake. Before this loop would stop at 1 and not check if index 0 was allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You want to zip them in a way that each word gets paired with the other words from the same index in each other list.  `zip` does that and you can used index 4 for each new list to keep or drop.  Then it's a matter of reshaping them back to the original form with `list(zip(*...)))`

```
LIST_1 =  ['english', 'english', 'french', 'english', 'english', 'english']
LIST_2  = ['documentation', 'music', 'position', 'social media', 'microeconomics', 'financial equations']
LIST_3 = ['ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12', 'ea_12']
LIST_4 = ['141031', '141032', '141033', '141034', '141035', '141036']
LIST_5 = ['allowed', 'allowed', 'rejected', 'allowed', 'rejected', 'allowed']
```

Edit:

To explain what's happening here, consider the inside zip

`tuple(zip(LIST_1,LIST_2,LIST_3,LIST_4,LIST_5))`

It's reshaping the data column-wise

```
(('english', 'documentation', 'ea_12', '141031', 'allowed'),
 ('english', 'music', 'ea_12', '141032', 'allowed'),
 ('french', 'position', 'ea_12', '141033', 'rejected'),
 ('english', 'social media', 'ea_12', '141034', 'allowed'),
 ('english', 'microeconomics', 'ea_12', '141035', 'rejected'),
 ('english', 'financial equations', 'ea_12', '141036', 'allowed'))
```

Here the last value in each group is at index 4, and is allowed/rejected, so in the list comprehension we keep only elements where the word at index 4 is 'allowed'

You can see that behavior here where what you get is a list of columns that pass the conditions:

```
[x for x in tuple(zip(LIST_1,LIST_2,LIST_3,LIST_4,LIST_5)) if x[4]=='allowed']
```

Output

```
[('english', 'documentation', 'ea_12', '141031', 'allowed'),
 ('english', 'music', 'ea_12', '141032', 'allowed'),
 ('english', 'social media', 'ea_12', '141034', 'allowed'),
 ('english', 'financial equations', 'ea_12', '141036', 'allowed')]
```

Now we can use `*` to unpack the list of tuples, and `zip` to change them back to row-wise, basically reversing the first `zip`.  Lastly you can assign them back to their original values.

The entire code.

```
LIST_1, LIST_2, LIST_3, LIST_4, LIST_5 = list(zip(*[x for x in tuple(zip(LIST_1,LIST_2,LIST_3,LIST_4,LIST_5)) if x[4]=='allowed']))
```

Comment: It works fine, I'm wondering how did you do that. It seems complex to me! And what x[4] refers to? Thank anyway.

Comment: @BACHASH Added some context to my answer.

Comment: That was very well explained. I learned a lot thank you.

Comment: I got an error when all the elements having 'rejected' in it saying: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 0). How to handle such an error or return an empty list in such cases?

Comment: @BACHASH  Then maybe use an if statement to check if all of the list_5 are rejected first, and if so just return empty lists for everything.